# How to print specific json array values in php script?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json array that looks like this:

```
{"server-host-01":{"API":"Good","JETS":"Good","HTTPD":"Good","DISK":"23% Used","CPU":"WARNING: Avg idle at: 98% "},"server-host-02":{"DISK":"18% Used","CPU":"Avg idle at: 99% "}}
```

I have a key then inside that key another array of key:values and then another key with the same setup of key:values inside.

In my php script i am assigning the json file to the variable of $files and then using json_decode to turn it into a php array (i think)

```
$files = (my_json_file.json);
    $string = file_get_contents($file);
    $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
```

Now i have the array in php i would like to print the main keys out and then print the key:values of the keys. They will be going into a html table but specially im looking for help printing out the values as i need them before i worry about the html part.

Comment: What have you tried, what is the actual problem? The data you have shown is not actually valid JSON btw.

Comment: Its worth pointing out i am pretty new to php and json. I have tried researching how to print specific values from arrays but i cant apply any examples to what i have. My problem is i dont know how to print specific values from my array. I guess that is a problem as well, can you tell me why its not valid json?

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ can tell you that. _“My problem is i dont know how to print specific values from my array.”_ - you either loop over your arrays, or you access specific items by their index / key. If you are unfamiliar with these basics, then you should go read up on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Viewing the JSON contents**

You have a JSON encoded array which contains two arrays inside of it as below (which I obtained via [this link](https://freeonlinetools24.com/json-decode)):

```
array (
  'server-host-01' => 
  array (
    'API' => 'Good',
    'JETS' => 'Good',
    'HTTPD' => 'Good',
    'DISK' => '23% Used',
    'CPU' => 'WARNING: Avg idle at: 98% ',
  ),
  'server-host-02' => 
  array (
    'DISK' => '18% Used',
    'CPU' => 'Avg idle at: 99% ',
  ),
)
```

If you wanted to view all values pertaining to server-host-01 you could do e.g.

`var_dump($json_a['server-host-01']);`

If you wanted only the CPU status you could to do e.g.

`$server_host_01_CPU_Status = $json_a['server-host-01']['CPU'];
 var_dump($server-host-01-CPU-Status);`

**Example code**

Here's an example of the above in action:

```
<?php

    $json = json_decode('{"server-host-01":{"API":"Good","JETS":"Good","HTTPD":"Good","DISK":"23% Used","CPU":"WARNING: Avg idle at: 98% "},"server-host-02":{"DISK":"18% Used","CPU":"Avg idle at: 99% "}}');

    $server_host_01_CPU_Status = $json['server-host-01']['CPU'];

    var_dump($server_host_01_CPU_Status);

    foreach($json['server-host-02'] as $key => $value)
    {
        var_dump("$key = $value");
    }

?>
```

**Other notes**

Your line `$files = (my_json_file.json);` is invalid PHP. I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but firstly:

1) `my_json_file.json` isn't wrapped in quotes so PHP is treating it as a constant variable rather than a string (and this throws an error too -- turn PHP server errors on to see it)

2) The unquoted string `my_json_file.json` is wrapped in parenthesis which doesn't even do anything in this case.

Assuming what you actually want is an array of file names to then open you'd want something like this:

```
$files = ['my_json_file.json'];
foreach($files as $file)
{
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $json = json_decode($contents, true);
    // foreach($json as $key => $value) { ...
}
```

I would highly recommend checking out [this tutorial](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-json-data-with-php-or-javascript/) for the basics on handing JSON data in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the tutorial. var_dump($json_a['server-host-01']); this line gives me a value of null and $server-host-01-CPU-Status = $json_a['server-host-01']['CPU'];
 var_dump($server-host-01-CPU-Status); seems to result in an error as my webpage is just blank with those two lines in. could the dashes in the server-host be causing a problem?

Comment: @a.smith You're welcome! It's maybe to do with "$files = (my_json_file.json);" as I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve there as it's invalid PHP. There is no "$file" variable in the code you've provided either. I've edited my answer to show some code that's definitely working

Comment: @a.smith just editing my answer now -- writing the code in an actual IDE the dashes in variable names is definitely breaking it. Give me a min

Comment: The idea behind the $files variable is to pick the .json file and then from there  turn it into the php array.

Comment: @a.smith I'm not 100% sure what you mean but I've edited my answer again

Comment: Thanks again @Max. You've got me much closer to my goal! One thing on my server-host-name is they change in the json file. A few steps before this to make up my json file im running another script that returns the host name and adds the values for things like CPU. Is there a way i can avoid hard coding in the server names in the lines:  $server_host_01_CPU_Status = $json_a['server-host-01']['CPU']; and: foreach($json['server-host-02'] as $key => $value)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200889/discussion-between-a-smith-and-max).